# Array keep on repeating in foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array holding string in it's values, I am finding underscore in each value breaking it and inserting it into new array, It's doing all right but only for first array in second array it repeats first array also.

**For Example**

```
$someArraVal[] = 'abc_xyz__vr1_vr2';
$someArraVal[] = 'emf_ccc__vr2_vr3';
```

First I am getting everything after double underscore then exploding them with underscore and trying to have array like below

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => vr1
        [1] => vr2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [2] => vr3
        [3] => vr4
    )
)
```

but I am getting

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => vr1
        [1] => vr2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => vr1
        [1] => vr2
        [2] => vr3
        [3] => vr4
    )
)
```

**CODE**

```
    $someArraVal[] = 'abc_xyz__vr1_vr2';
    $someArraVal[] = 'emf_ccc__vr3_vr4';

    $arr1 = [];
    $arr2 = [];
    $xmx = [];


    foreach ($someArraVal as $key => $value) {

        $afterunderscore = substr($value, strpos($value, "__") + 1);
        // $addPipe = str_replace("_","|",$afterunderscore);
        $abc = substr($afterunderscore, 1);
        $arr1 = explode('_',$abc);

        foreach ($arr1 as $k => $v) {
            $arr2[] = $v;
        }

        $xmx[] = $arr2;

    }

    printR($xmx);
```

Comment: You need to reset `$arr2` at each iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never reset `$arr2` so you append more data each iteration.

You can add `$arr2 = []` right after the `foreach`.

Better solution will be to do:

```
foreach ($someArraVal as $key => $value) {
    $afterunderscore = substr($value, strpos($value, "__") + 1);
    $xmx[] = explode('_',substr($afterunderscore, 1));
}
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/2XlAA)

Answer (score 2):

You need to empty the array `$arr2` at the start of foreach loop.

```
.
.
.


    foreach ($someArraVal as $key => $value) {

        $arr2 = []; //Empty the $arr2 at begining of the loop
        .
        .
        .

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Second array keeps repeating because you are looping inside the array which will take all the values.

<?php

$someArraVal[] = 'abc_xyz__vr1_vr2';
    $someArraVal[] = 'emf_ccc__vr3_vr4';

    $arr1 = [];
    foreach ($someArraVal as $key => $value) {

        $afterunderscore = substr($value, strpos($value, "__") + 1);
        $abc = substr($afterunderscore, 1);
        $arr1[] = explode('_',$abc);    
    }

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr1);
echo '</pre>';

Please check : https://prnt.sc/oitez2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another technique using a single iterated function call...

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1S7dT))

```
$someArraVal[] = 'abc_xyz__vr1_vr2';
$someArraVal[] = 'emf_ccc__vr2_vr3';

foreach ($someArraVal as $value) {
    $xmx[] = preg_split('~(?:[^_]+_)*_~', $value, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}

print_r($xmx);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => vr1
            [1] => vr2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => vr2
            [1] => vr3
        )

)
```

The pattern consumes the undesired substrings and treats them as delimiters.  This leaves you with only the substrings that you want.

---

If the idea of regex scares you, here's a non-regex solution with just two calls per iteration:

```
foreach ($someArraVal as $value) {
    $xmx[] = array_slice(explode('_', $value, 5), -2);
}
// same result array
```